# Change a monitor's color "profile" programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

Is there an API to set and then restore a display's color "profile" programmatically?

I've searched through CoreGraphics and, irrelevantly, ColorSync, and can only see means of retrieval (e.g, CGDisplayCopyColorSpace). The CG functions for setting displays seem to be about positioning and gamma etc, but not color profile management.

Note stack editors: This is indeed a programming question and not one about general computing. I'm looking to do this in Swift as part of an executable for the user. No need to close this.

#### Goal

Accurately sample sRGB pixel values, even if the monitor "profile" isn't sRGB

#### Observed behavior

Apps can set their own color environment. Depending on the sampled window, the raw BGRA values in a captured CGImage *may already be sRGB values* -- or need conversion.

You can test this in Apple's Digital Color Meter or any color picker. Apple's exactly reflects a CGImage capture BGRA raw pixel values.

Try sampling a swatch from Google's hex preview search result.

`Monitor in sRGB profile`

- Firefox — Values are accurate in “native” and “sRGB” sampling modes
- Safari — Ditto

`Monitor in any other color profile`

- Firefox — “Native” (raw CGImage BGRA values) are accurate sRGB values, but "sRGB" mode values are inaccurate
- Safari — Values are mostly inaccurate in either sampling mode, depending on the color

Accurately retrieving a screen cap RGB value requires (a) display profile being set (this is a known prerequisite) or (b) window-specific color space knowledge for appropriate conversion.

Comment: It sounds to me like you misunderstand how color management works. A monitor always uses the same color space (RGB, in almost all cases.) A managed color environment uses a source and destination color profile to map from your source color profile to the color profile of the display. RGB displays always use the RGB color space, and a color profile specific to that model of display (or ideally, a custom-generated profile for a specific instance of the display.)

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for the check-in. “Profile” is a shared vocabulary for us. A color space, to me, is a 3D volume defined mathematically by arbitrary primaries of convenience and/or from empirical measure. A display needn’t use canonical sRGB or even three primaries in its unique color space. A Mac’s “profile” choices are indeed volumetric color spaces and a transformation function creates a "profile" to bridge device and common spaces. Apple's ColorSync visualizes these spaces. But how we each relate to theory is beside the point. I’ve updated the description with a practical problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

[ColorSyncDeviceSetCustomProfiles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/colorsync/1460385-colorsyncdevicesetcustomprofiles) is what you're looking for.

Here's a working snippet for setting/resetting color profile for a `NSScreen`:

```swift
import ColorSync

let DEVICE_CLASS = kColorSyncDisplayDeviceClass.takeUnretainedValue()
let DEFAULT_PROFILE = kColorSyncDeviceDefaultProfileID.takeUnretainedValue()

extension NSScreen {
    var displayID: CGDirectDisplayID {
        deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as! CGDirectDisplayID
    }
    var cfUUID: CFUUID {
        CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID(displayID)!.takeRetainedValue()
    }
}

let RESET_PROFILE_DICT = [DEFAULT_PROFILE: nil] as CFDictionary
ColorSyncDeviceSetCustomProfiles(DEVICE_CLASS, NSScreen.main!.cfUUID, RESET_PROFILE_DICT)

let CUSTOM_PROFILE_DICT = [DEFAULT_PROFILE: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/ColorProfile.icc")] as CFDictionary
ColorSyncDeviceSetCustomProfiles(DEVICE_CLASS, NSScreen.main!.cfUUID, CUSTOM_PROFILE_DICT)
```

For convenience, I also provide source code and a compiled binary for setting color profiles here: [alin23/mac-utils - ApplyColorProfile](https://github.com/alin23/mac-utils/#applycolorprofile)